# Which of the open problems in Halmos's Lectures on Ergodic Theoy are still open today?

Tags: reference-request, ergodic-theory

For a while now, my bedtime reading has been a recent Dover reprint of Paul Halmos's 1956 booklet *Lectures on Ergodic Theory*. It's an interesting little work. At the end he lists a number of open problems in ergodic theory. Open, that is, in 1956. I imagine that some progress has since been made on at least some of these problems. So my question, directed mainly at those who have read the book *and* are knowledgeable about the current state of ergodic theory, is: what (major) modifications should I pencil into the margins on those pages? A somewhat related question: have any important new questions arisen in ergodic theory proper (not its applications to other mathematical areas per se) since Halmos's book?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Great question! It would take too much time to answer in detail, sorry, but besides problems 4, 5 and 10 (all of less general nature), to a large extent all others have been solved (6 was already solved when Halmos published the book). It is this "to a large extent" that would take too much time to detail.